# Perl split pattern

Tags: regex, perl

According to the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), the syntax for split is:

> ```
> split /PATTERN/,EXPR,LIMIT
> ```

But the `PATTERN` can also be a single- or double-quoted string: `split "PATTERN", EXPR`. What difference does it make?

Edit: A difference I'm aware of is splitting on backslashes: `split /\\/` vs `split '\\'`. The second form doesn't work.

Comment: The difference you're seeing is caused by interpolation. `/\\/` is a pattern containing a single backslash. `'\\'` is a string containing a single backslash. When that string is interpreted as a pattern it's as if you'd written `/\/`, which is invalid. To get the same behavior you'd have to double up the backslashes: `'\\\\'`

Comment: @Michael: these are called backslash escape sequences, not interpolation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it uses that as "an expression to specify patterns":

> The pattern /PATTERN/  may be replaced
>   with an expression to specify patterns
>   that vary at runtime. (To do runtime
>   compilation only once, use
>   /$variable/o .)

edit: I tested it with this:

```
my $foo = 'a:b:c,d,e';
print join(' ', split("[:,]", $foo)), "\n";
print join(' ', split(/[:,]/, $foo)), "\n";
print join(' ', split(/\Q[:,]\E/, $foo)), "\n";
```

Except for the `' '` special case, it looks just like a regular expression.

Comment: One example where it doesn't: `split /\\/` vs `split '\\'`.

Comment: To be more precise, `split EXPR, ...` (where EXPR is not a literal `/.../`) is roughly equivalent to `do { my $pattern = EXPR; split /$pattern/, ... }` (except for the `' '` special case).  That's why `'\\'` doesn't work; the resulting `$pattern` contains only 1 backslash, and you need 2 to have a valid regex.

Answer (score 2):

`PATTERN` is always interpreted as... well, a pattern -- never as a literal value. It can be either a regex<sup>1</sup> or a string. Strings are compiled to regexes. For the most part the behavior is the same, but there can be subtle differences caused by the double interpretation.

The string `'\\'` only contains a single backslash. When interpreted as a pattern, it's as if you had written `/\/`, which is invalid:

```
C:\>perl -e "print join ':', split '\\', 'a\b\c'"
Trailing \ in regex m/\/ at -e line 1.
```

Oops!

Additionally, there are two special cases:

- The empty pattern `//`, which splits on the empty string.
- A single space `' '`, which splits on whitespace after first trimming any
   leading or trailing whitespace.

<sub>1. Regexes can be supplied either inline `/.../` or via a precompiled `qr//` quoted string.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's no difference. A string pattern is also interpreted as a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -e 'print join("-",split("[a-e]","regular"))';
r-gul-r
```

As you see, the delimiter is interpreted as a regular expression, not a string literal.

So, it's mostly the same - with one important exception:  `split(" ",...`  ) and  `split(/  /,...`  ) are different.

I prefer to use `/PATTERN/` to avoid confusion, it's easy to forget that it's a regexp otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Two observable rules:

- the special case `split(" ")` is equivalent to `split(/\s+/)`.
- for everything else (it seems—don't nail me), `split("something")` is equal to `split(/something/)`

Comment: It doesn't treat it with `\Q\E` at all; it just treats it as `/something/`.

Comment: That's not correct. A string behaves just like a standard regex.

Comment: `split ' '` is like `split /\s+/` except that the former skips a leading empty field.